# Get JAX-RS AsyncResponse, but suspend later

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, jax-rs

Consider the following code to listen for an update with long-polling:

```
Map<String, List<AsyncResponse>> tagMap = new ConcurrentGoodStuff();

// This endpoint listens for notifications of the tag
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@GET
@Path("listen/{tag}")
public void listenForUpdates(
        @PathParam("tag") final String tag,
        @Suspended final AsyncResponse response) {
    tagMap.get(tag).add(response);
}

// This endpoint is for push-style notifications
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@PUT
@Path("update/{tag}/{value}")
public Response updateTag(
        @PathParam("tag") final String tag,
        @PathParam("value") final String value) {
    for(AsyncResponse response : tagMap.get(tag)) {
        // Resumes all previously suspended responses
        response.resume(value);
    }
    return Response.ok("cool whatever").build();
}
```

The client adds a listener with the normal Jersey client's `AsyncInvoker`, calls the asynchronous task, and then another task calls the update method.

When I'm testing this, I run into a race condition. Right after I add the listener asynchronously on `listenForUpdates()`, I make an update on the endpoint with `updateTag()` synchronously. But the update gets run before the listener is added, and the asynchronous response fails to resume.

A solution to this is to call the `suspend()` method on the response *after* adding it to the listeners. But it's not clear how to do that, given that `@Suspended` provides an already-suspended `AsyncResponse` object. What should I do so that the async response is suspended *only after* adding to listener? Will that actually call the suspend method? How can I get this to work with the Jersey async client, or should I use a different long-polling client?

For solutions, I'm open to different libraries, like Atmosphere or Guava. I am not open to adding a `Thread.sleep()` in my test, since that is an intermittent failure waiting to happen.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do, but you should look at some of the examples in the Jersey project. There's a bunch of different async example. I think one of the chat example kinda does what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think [this is the one](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/server-async-managed).  Not sure if that's exactly what you're trying to do though

Comment: I think the blocking queue is definitely the way to go if I want to ensure consumption precedes a check for consumption. I currently have updates always being non-blocking. If I add a flag to optionally block on a listener being updated, it will definitely help for testing. Cool, I think I'll do this. Thank you. Add this as a "real answer" and I'll pass some internet points on to you.

Comment: I'm still not really sure how it solves your problem as I wasn't totally clear on what the problem was. I was simply making a mental connection between two things that I _thought_ may be connected. It's probably better if you posted the answer with example code of what you did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using RxJava, but not before coming up with a just-as-good solution using [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) instead of `List` in the `Map`. It goes something like this:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, BlockingQueue<AsyncResponse>> tagMap = new ConcurrentGoodStuff();

// This endpoint initiates a listener array for the tag.
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@GET
@Path("initListen/{tag}")
public void listenForUpdates(
        @PathParam("tag") final String tag) {
    tagMap.putIfAbsent(tag, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
}

// This endpoint listens for notifications of the tag
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@GET
@Path("listen/{tag}")
public void listenForUpdates(
        @PathParam("tag") final String tag,
        @Suspended final AsyncResponse response) {
    BlockingQueue<AsyncResponse> responses = tagMap.get(tag);

    if (responses != null) {
        responses.add(response);
    }
}

// This endpoint is for push-style notifications
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@PUT
@Path("update/{tag}/{value}")
public Response updateTag(
        @PathParam("tag") final String tag,
        @PathParam("value") final String value) {
    BlockingQueue<AsyncResponse> responses = tagMap.get(tag);

    if (responses == null) {
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }
    if (responses.isEmpty()) {
        // Block-wait for an async listener
        try {
            AsyncResponse response = tagMap.poll(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            if (response == null) {
                return Response.noContent().build();
            }

            response.resume(value);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return Response.noContent().build();
        }
    } else {
        for (AsyncResponse response : responses) {
            // Resumes all previously suspended responses
            response.resume(value);
        }
    }
    return Response.ok("cool whatever").build();
}
```

I haven't tested this exact code, but I used some version of it in the past. As long as you call the `initListen` endpoint synchronously first, you can call the asynchronous `listen` endpoint and then the synchronous `update` endpoint and there won't be any significant race condition.

There is a slight hint of a race condition in the `update` endpoint, but it's minor. The `responses` blocking queue could become empty on iteration, or it may be updated by multiple sources differently. To alleviate this, I've used the [`drainTo(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo(java.util.Collection)) method on a per-request instantiated data structure. This still does not solve the use case where multiple clients may try updating the same tag of listeners, but I do not need this use case.